# Multi Looping and Multi Splitting of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a CSV file with 22000 rows of author names.

1. Each row has multiple author names delimited by ';'.
2. Each author name in a row is in 'lastName, firstName' order.

I want to split them and append to new columns like below.

***Raw dataset preview***:

```
+------------------------------------+
|           author_full_name         |
+------------------------------------+
| Kahana, M J; Adler, M              |
|Gautam, H; Potdar, G G; Vidya, T N C|
+------------------------------------+
```

***Expected output***:

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|           author_full_name         | author_first_names| author_last_names    |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Kahana, M J; Adler, M              |      M J; M       | Kahana; Adler        |
|Gautam, H; Potdar, G G; Vidya, T N C|     H; G G; T N C | Gautam; Potdar; Vidya|
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

How can I accomplish this with pandas?

Answer (score 1):

The logic here essentially is to first split by `;` then split each of the values by  `,` and get their firstvalue as ;ast name and 2nd values as first name

```
>>> [x.split(",")[0] for x in "Gautam, H; Potdar, G G; Vidya, T N C".split(";")]
>>> ['Gautam', ' Potdar', ' Vidya']
```

In pandas using apply:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Gautam, H; Potdar, G G; Vidya, T N C","Kahana, M J; Adler, M "]})
df['author_last_names'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ";".join([ele.split(",")[1] for ele in x.split(";")]))
df['author_first_names'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ";".join([ele.split(",")[0] for ele in x.split(";")]))

df
```

**Output:**

```
------------------------------------|-----------------|------------------------
Gautam, H; Potdar, G G; Vidya, T N C  H; G G; T N C      Gautam; Potdar; Vidya
Kahana, M J; Adler, M                 M J; M             Kahana; Adler
------------------------------------|-----------------|------------------------
```